# Objective-C++ executable file compilation (with .mm)

Tags: xcode, templates, std, linker-errors, objective-c++

Intro. I am facing a strange error with Objective-C++. All my files are of the correct type (.h/.mm instead of .hpp/.cpp). I use clib++ (built into xCode of latest version on macOS Sierra, but it was the same way on El Capitan) instead of libstd++ (that is older and doesn't fully support even C++11).

The problem. **I can't compile template classes with both header and executable files. Only in case if entire code is written in header!**

However, if I make a non-template class it works just fine even when split into 2 files. Header:

```
class TempClass {
public:
    TempClass(int x);
    ~TempClass() {};
};
```

Executable:

```
TempClass::TempClass(int x) {}
```

**Template class code**. Header:

```
template <typename T> class TempClassTemplate {
public:
    TempClassTemplate(T v);
    ~TempClassTemplate() {};
    T val;
};
```

Executable:

```
template<typename T> TempClassTemplate<T>::TempClassTemplate(T v) : val(v) {};
```

Usage example, that causes crash:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {    
    auto obj = new TempClass(5);
    printf("temp size is %lu\n", sizeof(obj));
    auto objV = new TempClassTemplate<int>(10);
    printf("temp size is %lu, val is %i\n", sizeof(objV), objV->val);

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with Objective-C or Objective-C++. Its pure C++ known issue, but the compiler gives not enough info.
You can only make a template class - header only. But there are some walkarounds. Read this article for full answer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp

But the short and simple solution is to write all the possible template class usages in the end of .cpp/.mm file like this:

```
template class TempClassTemplate<int8_t>;
template class TempClassTemplate<int16_t>;
template class TempClassTemplate<int32_t>;
```